# AVCaptureSession cancels background audio

Tags: iphone, audio, ios, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

Whenever I start an AVCaptureSession running with the microphone as an input it cancels whatever background music is currently running (iPod music for instance).  If I comment out the line adding the audio input, the background audio continues.

Does anyone know of a way to record video clips with the microphone while continuing to allow background audio to play?  I've looked around a lot, and can't seem to find any references to this behavior.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Look into kAudioSessionCategory.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers as seen in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7426406/16572

Answer (score 1):

Is the background music a looping track? -- if so you could make it a system sound and tell it to re-play when it finishes playing. The reason being you can only have tracks up to 30 seconds as a system sound.

Don't know if it helps -- but thats one approach :)

Cheers,

Michael

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and used this in my app and it worked:

```
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionCategory_AmbientSound;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
```

I was able to record video and audio and at the same time play a sound out of the speakers.

Comment: Where did you add this? Audio playback from the iPod app always stops, when I add the audio AVCaptureDeviceInput to my capture session… I tried this code before adding this and before creating the capture device…

Comment: Where and how to use this? can anyone please explain.

Comment: Hi Scoota can you please provide more context?