# Is it possible to record video with AVAssetWriter and still playback background sounds

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, avassetwriter, avaudiosession

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AVCaptureSession cancels background audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490786/avcapturesession-cancels-background-audio)

I am using AVCaptureSession to record video asset with no sound. But is it possible to configure AVAudioSession to continue iPod audio playing background music?

Comment: What do you mean by background music?

Comment: Lets assume, that we are listening Music Player in background mode. Then we are starting our app and initialize AVCaptureSession with video device only. The Music Player stops playing :-(

Answer (score 0):

I have not used AVAssetWriter yet, but I am planning to.

So far, I got a `AVAudioRecorder` recording at the same time as an `AVAudioPlayer` is playing music in my app.

Edit: But now it seems like that's not what you were looking for. Maybe try to revise your question for clearness and it might get some more answers. :)