# Using vibrate and AVCaptureSession at the same time

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, avcapturesession

I'm trying to vibrate the phone while recording video, but I'm finding that `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);` doesn't play nicely with `AVCaptureSession`.  Is there any other way to vibrate the phone or am I stuck with losing the vibrate function while recording video?

Comment: I would think vibration would negatively affect the quality of the captured video. This could be why it's disabled.

Comment: @picciano It's not just vibrate though, its any system sound

Answer (score 6):

You probably need to set the audio to mix with other, I found this useful:

```
- (void)setupAudio {
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];
    UInt32 doSetProperty = 1;
    AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof(doSetProperty), &doSetProperty);
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
}
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411793/avassetreader-kills-playback-in-avaudioplayer/7426406#7426406)

Comment: can u please explain me how to do it??? i want to vibrate the phone while recording the video... please guide me

Comment: here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059607/how-to-use-vibration-while-recording-iphone5-ios

Comment: Hello @User1531343, Did you find any solution? I want to implement same feature in my app.